# right shifting the double variable

Tags: c, double

hi I want to do the followed task:

```
double time;
char array[6];
for(int index=0; index<6; index++){
  array[index]=(char)(time>>(8*index));
}
```

but the error appears: expresion must have integral or unscoped enum

Comment: What do you expect right-shifting a double to do?

Comment: read up on how a double is represented in memory, then you will understand why shifting it makes no sense.

Comment: I have a great number which should be packed in a array and the array should be placed in data frame

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Can you explain how you want to place the double in the array? The array is 6 bytes, and (typically) a double is 8 bytes, so all of the double won't fit.

Comment: that is right. as a matter of fact, i am working on DNP3 protocol and it uses  six bytes time stamp field

Answer (score 4):

From ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (a.k.a. C99 standard):

> ### 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.

If you want to *divide* `time` by 2 to the power of `(8*index)`, you can either:

1. Use `pow()` from math.h, or
2. Create an integer variable with value `1 << (8*index)`, then divide time by this variable

If you want to actually do a bit shift of the binary representation of the IEEE floating point number<sup>(1)</sup> (not that I understand why you would want to do that), you can do the following:

```
uint64_t x = *(uint64_t *)&time;
array[index]=(char)(x>>(8*index));
```

<sup>(1): Assuming your implementation uses IEEE floating point</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Right shifting a float or double is almost certainly not what you meant to do, as the data representation is not one that would be affected by right shift as division by a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use right-shifting operator for double variable.